# How to test if strdup() is available?

Tags: c, gcc, posix

I'm using this:

```
#if !defined(_SVID_SOURCE) || !defined(_BSD_SOURCE) || _XOPEN_SOURCE < 500 || !(_XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) \
|| _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 200809L
char * strdup(const char *s)
{
  char *buffer = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);

  if(buffer != NULL)
    strcpy(buffer, s);

  return buffer;
}
#endif
```

But is there the possibility to get a redeclaration error? Maybe into some gcc version or gcc-like compiler? I want to make it compatible with versions (standards) where there is no `strdup()`, `-ansi`, for example.

Also, how can I make it more portable?

Comment: What compiler/environment are you targeting where this is a problem?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I'm sorry. english isn't my native language.

Comment: NP, Jack; we're here to help.  Someone should go back and do some more work, but I need to get into the office.  Note that part of the problem is whether `strdup()` is present in the system libraries; the other part is whether `strdup()` is declared in the system headers.  The `strdup()` function can be present in the system libraries without being declared by the headers (perhaps because the user chose a poor value of one of the configuration macros, such as `_XOPEN_SOURCE`).  Ideally, you want both the declaration and the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely the wrong use of feature test macros. Feature test macros are not defined by the implementation to tell the application what's available; they're defined by the application to request that the implementation provide conformance to (a particular version of) a particular standard.

The macros you should be using to test for a what the implementation supports are in `unistd.h`:

- `_POSIX_VERSION` - version of POSIX supported. `200809L` is latest.
- `_XOPEN_VERSION` - version of X/Open Portability Guide, now called the "XSI" option of POSIX. Latest is `700` (from SUSv4). `600` (SUSv3) is common. `500` (SUSv2) is badly outdated.
- `_POSIX_THREADS` - version of pthreads (should be the same as `_POSIX_VERSION`; mandatory since POSIX 2008)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it's already defined you will get redeclaration on strdup. The only way I know to get around this type of issue is to macro strdup to something else (say _strdup) and then define strdup with that other name. This is a little ugly but it gets the job done.

To your first question, no you can't determine if a function exists with the preprocessor. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749233/check-whether-function-is-declared-with-c-preprocessor).

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the `string.h` on my platform (linux, gnu libc 2.16) I found :

```
#if defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED \
    || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8
/* Duplicate S, returning an identical malloc'd string.  */
extern char *strdup (const char *__s)
     __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __nonnull ((1));
#endif
```

The `#if`s are slightly different, I don't know the influence between those I found in my header and the ones your are using.
About the second question, you could use the [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) to create a `config.h` header describing the capabilities of the compiling platform, and use your own versions of missing functions.
In addition you could also use the [gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) "source library" which provides implementation of defective or missing functions (like [`strdup`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/strdup.html))
Using autotools should prevent any redeclaration error.