# Is there any way to check whether a function has been declared?

Tags: c++, c, function, function-prototypes

Suppose there's a library, one version of which defines a function with name `foo`, and another version has the name changed to `foo_other`, but both these functions still have the same arguments and return values. I currently use conditional compilation like this:

```
#include <foo.h>
#ifdef USE_NEW_FOO
#define trueFoo foo_other
#else
#define trueFoo foo
#endif
```

But this requires some external detection of the library version and setting the corresponding compiler option like `-DUSE_NEW_FOO`. I'd rather have the code automatically figure what function it should call, based on it being declared or not in `<foo.h>`.

Is there any way to achieve this in any version of C?

If not, will switching to any version of C++ provide me any ways to do this?  (assuming the library does all the needed actions like `extern "C"` blocks in its headers)? Namely, I'm thinking of somehow making use of [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/), but for a global function, rather than method, which was discussed in the linked question.

Comment: with gcc ... maybe something like `prototype ... foo ... __attribute__ ((alias ("foo_other")));` ... see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749233/check-whether-function-is-declared-with-c-preprocessor

Comment: @BrianSidebotham no it's not. I didn't specify that one must use preprocessor. Also I ask for alternative ways like switching to C++.

Comment: C++ is not a superset of C. You can't just go ahead and  start compiling your code as C++ code.

Comment: @Columbo that's not a problem, assume I can port it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you can use expression SFINAE for this:

```
//this template only enabled if foo is declared with the right args
template <typename... Args>
auto trueFoo (Args&&... args) -> decltype(foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//ditto for fooOther
template <typename... Args>
auto trueFoo (Args&&... args) -> decltype(fooOther(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return fooOther(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are *statically* linking to a function, in most versions of C++, the name of the function is "mangled" to reflect its argument list.  Therefore, an attempt to *statically* link to the library, by a program with an out-of-date `.hpp` file, will result in an "unknown symbol" linker-error.

In the C language, there's no metadata of any kind which indicates what the argument list of any exported function *actually* is.

Realistically, I think, you simply need to be *sure* that the `.h` or `.hpp` files that you're using to link to a library, actually reflect the corresponding object-code within whatever version of that library you are using. You also need to be sure that the `Makefile` (or "auto-make" process) will correctly identify any-and-all modules within your application which link-to that library and which therefore must be recompiled in case of any changes to it.  (If it were me, I would recompile the entire application.)  In short, *you* must see to it that this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: As I noted after the C++-related part of question, assume that the function is declared in an `extern "C"` block, so the name won't get mangled.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  And, if the name is "not mangled," the linker will have no way to know whether the actual binary code to which it (successfully) links your code, actually matches the `.h` or `.hpp` file that you used when compiling.  And there's no way that it could.  Realistically, I think that this is just like what faces you if the meaning of an existing external-subroutine gets changed:  *you* have to be the one to keep on top of such things.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//#define DEFINE_F

#ifdef DEFINE_F
void f()
{

}
#endif

namespace
{
    constexpr struct special
    {
      std::false_type operator()() const;
    }f; 
}

struct checkForF
{
    static const constexpr auto value = std::conditional< std::is_same<std::false_type, decltype(::f())>::value, std::false_type, std::true_type >::type();
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << checkForF::value << std::endl;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/WNvmbv)

Please note I only handle f without any parameters.