# Test Availability of x_np pthread Functions - C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, portability

I am writing a helper library for threading in C, based on the pthread API. There are many pthread functions that are nonstandard GNU extensions, such as `pthread_set_affinity_np`, `pthread_clear_exit_np`, `pthread_set_qos_class_self_np`, etc.

**Is there any way I can use macros to test whether these non portable functions are available without looking up which operating systems define what?**

Comment: `dlopen()` the `pthread`-library, then `dlsym()` for the function-name?

Comment: @EOF I've never heard of either of those functions. I'll look them up.

Comment: @EOF It seems like those functions are called at run time aren't they? Ideally I would like a preprocessor solution.

Comment: The "preprocessor solution" is called a macro. Something like `#ifdef pthread_set_affinity_np`

Comment: @EOF Yes in my question I asked if there was a way to use macros for this.

Comment: @EOF Are those macros?

Comment: @EOF also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749233/check-whether-function-is-declared-with-c-preprocessor) says that your example would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of problem that people use Autoconf to solve.  Eg a sinppet like this in your `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_CHECK_DECLS(
  [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np, pthread_clear_exit_np, pthread_set_qos_class_self_np],
  [], [], [[#include <pthread.h>]])
```

will define macros `HAVE_DECL_PTHREAD_ATTR_SETAFFINITY_NP`, `HAVE_DECL_PTHREAD_CLEAR_EXIT_NP` and `HAVE_DECL_PTHREAD_SET_QOS_CLASS_SELF_NP`, defined to `0` if the declaration is not present or `1` if it is.

Comment: I would have never thought of autoconf. I've never used it before. Thanks for the tip.